# jQuery Context Menu open Dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog, contextmenu

It works for A Href with link (a href="www.google.com") but not with the hash # e.g (a href="#"). What i want to do is open jquery dialog when clicking one of the context menu items which contains # href. Fyi, using standard links without jquery context menu works fine with or without #.

My code:

```
<ul id="myMenu" class="contextMenu">
    <li><a href="#" id='cmsharefolder_link' class='sharefolder_link'>
        <img src='../style/images/sharefolders.png' title='Share' />
        Share
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="move_link" >
        <img src="../style/images/move.png" title="Move Folder"/>
        Move</a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Jquery context menu:

```
    $(document).ready( function() {

        // Show menu when #myDiv is clicked
        $("#list TR").contextMenu({
            menu: 'myMenu'
        },

        function(action, el, pos) {
            $(el).attr('id').trigger('click');
        }

        );

    });
```

Dialog for the #:

```
    $(function(){
        // Dialog for moving file / folder      
        $('.move').dialog({ autoOpen: false, width: 600, modal: true });

        // Dialog for moving file / folder link
        $('.move_link').click(function(){ $('.move').dialog('open'); return false; });  

        // Dialog for moving file / folder      
        $('.sharefolder').dialog({ autoOpen: false, width: 600, modal: true });

        // Dialog for share folder link
        $('.sharefolder_link').click(function(){ $('.sharefolder').dialog('open'); sharedfolder(); return false; });                
    });
```

The Answer is in comments by kannix using action parameters (e.g. Quit)

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try with

```
href="javascript:void(0)"
```